# Detecting if there is a change in a localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a case where I need to pass a variable from a modal back to the main screen. I have decided the cleanest way to do so is to store that value in `localStorage` so that I can pass it back to the main file and then display it on the main page.

Is there a way to listen to the `localStorage` item being changed? I've been searching, but only have found information getting and setting the variable.

My item looks like this.

```
var length = $('.table').find('tbody').find('tr').length;
localStorage.setItem('length', length);
```

Comment: In one of the comments on one of the answers, you mentioned a database.  If you are trying to replicate this through to a database, you need to add that to this question.  The answers become significantly different under those circumstances.

Comment: @zero298, I did not mention the database in the question because I cannot make a database call. This needs to happen on the fly when a modal is closed. This for display purposes only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a storage event on window object for local storage changes.

[MDN local storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent)

So you can watch the changes. But, if I am correct, that would work only for the same domain frames. So if they are, this is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global scope like define it out of function and it will be one global scope.

```
  var globalVariable={
       x: 'globalval'
    };
```

or use...

```
window.globalvar1='test'  //it will set to global.
```

that way it will be bind to window scope.

Comment: I cannot do this unfortunately as I am working with two different files. Why I wanted to use localstorage.

Comment: that doesn't matter... still if its other files they have global scope and it call window....

Comment: There is an issue of iframes in the mix as well. It's long and complicated. I have tried this it will not work.

Comment: then you should ask other q....how to pass data from iframe to parent...

Comment: It's more complex that that. It's an iframe within a modal to an iframe within an iframe. Why I was trying to go around that

Answer (score 0):

when you set the item, always first do a get and compare with that value,
if value is changed notify, otherwise set.

```
var length = $('.table').find('tbody').find('tr').length;
    if(localStorage.getItem(length)){
    localStorage.getItem(length)!=length?notifyChange(): 

    }
```

Comment: I need to get the item elsewhere in a separate file.  I need something to listen for the change when it happens within the modal

Comment: publish a custom event whenever something is getting added to local storage.....and subscribe in the different file where you need.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is an expensive and overly complicated approach but meets your needs for pure localStorage.

If you must use localStorage the only way I can think of that you can watch/listen for a variable in localStorage is like so

```
setInterval(function(){
    var modalValue = localStorage.getItem( 'length' );

    if( modalValue ){
        // use the value
        // remove the value when you are done so that this code doesn't run every time
        localStorage.setItem( 'length', null );
    }
}, 100 );
```

This will check for the variable every 1/10 of a second and run the code when it's set.

You mentioned in a comment that it is complicated and that their are iframes involved. Perhaps you can leverage the [messaging api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to better meet your needs?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use localstorage for critical functionality. localstorage is blocked completely when using private browsing on certain browsers.

Only use localstorage for non-critical enhancements.

There is no callback for localstorage, so you wont be able to monitor changes as they happen. You could however pull the value on page load, store the value in your execution context and watch for that value to change.

Otherwise, to do what you want will require using a database.

Comment: How would he do what he wants *without* using `localStorage`?

Comment: He wants to communiate between scripts on two different pages.

Comment: This is not critical data. It's displaying a number. So how would you propose doing this without local storage. I am passing this value between two different files and this was the only way I could come up with. It cannot happen on load of page.

Comment: You could use Cookies - or preferably a database.  I have a cookie getter setter here that you can use if needed:

https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/xdfopxa7/

Comment: I have a database, this change needs to happen on the fly without reloading the page or making another database call.

Comment: @zazvorniki Why didn't you mention replicating data to a database in your question?  That changes the ball game entirely.

Comment: Because I was trying to purely use localstoage and not use the database.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this, find a mechanism of dependency injection that will let you pass the the variable in a sane manner.  Do that either with something akin to Angular.js' service/factory pattern, or a React store.

Leveraging a mechanism like that will also allow you to listen for changes to whatever you're storing.  In fact, that's the whole point of things like RxJS Observables which are at the core of Angular2+'s framework.

Additionally, something like couchdb would let you persist this data asynchronously and still not have the drawbacks of coordinating globals through raw localstorage.

Allowing for uncontrolled access to some global variable is just asking for a defect.

Comment: I cannot use a library. I am within a huge application. This is just for one small number to display to the user. Nothing huge...